# How to call an async function in pytest_sessionfinish()?

Tags: python, asynchronous, pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I am using `pytest-asyncio`.

I have the following `conftest.py` file:

```
import asyncio

import pytest
from database.mongo_db import mongo


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
async def initialise_db():
    await mongo.connect_client()
    await mongo.drop_db()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    yield asyncio.new_event_loop()
```

The `initialise_db()` function will connect to my database and clear everything from it before all of my tests are run.

Now, I want to close the event loop and also close the connection to my database once all tests are complete. I have tried adding the following function to `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().close()
    mongo.disconnect_client()
```

However, this new function has two issues:

1. `asyncio.get_event_loop().close()` raises a warning: `DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop`
2. `mongo.disconnect_client()` is an async function. If I change `pytest_sessionfinish` to an async function and use `await` when closing the database, then I get the warning: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'pytest_sessionfinish' was never awaited`, and this is called from within pytest, so I cannot change it to be awaited unless I edit the source code. Of course, if I don't make it an async function I get the warning: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'disconnect_client' was never awaited`.

How can I resolve these two issues?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't. Pytests manages the event loop and you shouldn't (and needn't) interfere with that.
   [EDIT: Ok, sorry. Interfere, if you have to... For example to extend the scope of the event_loop fixture.]
2. Fixtures should take care of their own teardown. Just define it as a yield fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
async def initialise_db():
    await mongo.connect_client()
    await mongo.drop_db()
    yield # suspended until tests are done
    await mongo.disconnect_client() # pytest calls teardown when fixture goes out of scope
```

The `event_loop`fixture is provided by default by pytest-asyncio, but can be overridden to change the scope or provide a custom loop. See pytest-asyncio [readme](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio#event_loop) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I understand point 1, but when I use your solution given (with `scope="session"`) I get the following error: `ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'event_loop' with a 'session' scoped request object`. For now, I can use this fixture with the default `function` scope, but I think in the future I will have to change the scope to `session` so that my database stays persisted across all tests.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the scope issue. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your comment. You defined an `event_loop` fixture yourself in your example with a "session"-scope. Why does pytest complain, that you defined your event loop with "function"-scope?

Comment: when I try your updated solution I am getting the following warning: `DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop` which causes my tests to fail (I presume because no event loop is being returned), hence why my original solution used `asyncio.new_event_loop()`.

Comment: I didn't get that `DeprecationWarning` since I'm still on Python 3.8... Does it work if you use `new_event_loop()` instead? I can't easily test this right now, but I don't see why it shouldn't work. I'll update the example.